# Prevent inserting duplicate incrementing value on database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a program that saves records of amount on database. Each current inserted amount relies on previous saved amount and incremented from that value.

It's like:

```
select amount from table order by id desc limit 1;
```

then I will increment the latest amount available with my current amount and insert it as new row.

Let's say the first amount on database is 100, the next amounts to be inserted are 150, 30 and 70. This is how the logic goes:

**before**

```
id  -   amount
1   -   100
```

**after**

```
id  -   amount
1   -   100
2   -   250 (get previous 100, then add 150)
3   -   280 (get previous 250, then add 30)
4   -   350 (get previous 280, then add 70)
```

But the problem is when I make this process multiple times (the php process is triggered via ajax on every click), it makes some records duplicate, which is wrong:

**what happens when the process was made multiple times**

```
id  -   amount
1   -   100
2   -   250 (get previous 100, then add 150)
3   -   130 (get previous 250, then add 30)
4   -   200 (get previous 280, then add 70)
```

Seems like, when I insert the **id# 3**, the value saved on the database found on select is still 100 and the 250 was not yet inserted that's why the new inserted data takes the older value.

Is there any other way to do this kind of process that will prevent me so save a duplicate amount or increment from older amount values from db?

What I've tried so far is to put a datetime and make the request valid every 1 second based on the previous saved datetime. Still not working. Maybe because the mysql is slow, Im not sure.

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions come to mind.

Transactions. These will let you fetch the last row and add a new one as a group. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx
I "think" these would work in your case though I am not certain.

Table locking. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables.html - that has it's own pros and cons.

Also you could perform 3 queries - an insert with the non padded amount which then returns the ID, a select of the row before, then an update which updates the amount. Like this (Pseudo code):

```
1. insert into table (amount) values (30)
2. get last inserted id (assuming autoincrement else you could use timestamps and get the last row before the timestamp used in #1)
3. select from table where id = (last_inserted_id - 1)
4. update where id=last_inserted_id set amount += (#3 amount)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your fast response. I also come up with table locking thing idea :). But is it like when i do insert and process is not yet done, the table will be locked and other user who will be using same process will be disabled for a while until the process of previous user is done?

Comment: Yes - hence the pros and cons :).  I think my last suggestion should work. I've added some pseudo code to make it clearer.

Comment: Using transaction is the best solution :D